# How to calculate the square root of matrix $A+B$ perturbatively?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A=diag\{\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n\}$ and $\lambda_i>0$, $B$ is a positive definite symmetric matrix and  $max\{B_{ij} \}\ll min\{\lambda_i\}$

Note that the perturbative calculation of square root of $I+B$ is very easy, where $B$ is a small matrix.

How to calculate the square root of $A+B$ perturbatively?

Comment: Double post cf. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/193905/how-to-calculate-the-square-root-of-matrix-ab-perturbatively

Comment: Please don't post the same question to more than one StackExchange site at a time.